# Python SDK for HTML to PDF Conversion

Tags: python, sdk, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

There are many options to convert PDF from HTML string / file. However, most of them seem to accept only through the RestAPIs to their server. Are there SDKs or options to host the server internally so that the data is not sent outside of the internal network?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, why host the server locally at all? Is it just the webpage you want to save as a pdf, or specific information?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a web service. Just that data shouldn't be sent outside.

Comment: So if I understand your goal: you have HTML pages that you want to convert to PDFs? I would just use any number of existing python libraries for it. Specifically this looks pretty easy to use: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-html-pdf/